# Remove object inside array items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array of objects like so:

Main Array:

```js
[
  {
    "controller": "Education",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Insert",
        "controller": "Education",
        "id": 1
      }...etc
    ]
  },
  {
    "controller": "CustomerPackage",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Insert",
        "controller": "CustomerPackage",
        "id": 1
      }..etc
    ]
  }
]
```

Have the selected list similar as above list.
if there are items in the selected list, I want to remove them from the main array

Here's what I've tried so far, any ideas?

```
this.mainArray.map(item => { 
  let subItemId = parseInt(item.items.map(i => i.id)); 
  this.selectedArray.map(v => { 
    v.items.map(j => { 
      if (subItemId == j.id) { 
        console.log("how can i make for mainArray list "); 
        console.log(j.name); 
      } 
    }) 
  })
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried as of now?

Comment: There are 2 array lists. one is "main array" and the other is "selected array". if the selected list is the same, I want to remove it from the "main array" list
what should i use? filter? map?

Comment: Ideally, filter should be used. But as you told that you have tried with it, I want you to post what you have already tried so that we can improvise that or suggest something new.

Comment: this.mainArray.map(item => {
      let subItemId = parseInt(item.items.map(i => i.id));
      this.selectedArray.map(v => {
        v.items.map(j => {
          if (subItemId == j.id) {
            console.log("how can i make for mainArray list ");
            
            console.log(j.name);
          }
        })

      })

i tried it. but im not sure

Comment: @aykut The first thing that sticks out to me is how you are getting `subItemId`. Your code shows you've done `item.items.map(i => i.id)`, which will return an array of numbers, like so: `[1, 2, 3, ...]`. calling `parseInt()` will simply return the first element in the array, ignoring the rest of the IDs. Is this what you are intending to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an auxiliary variable to get the position of the item in the list you want to delete.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var positionList = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] == 4)
      positionList = i;
}
myArray.splice(positionList, 1);
alert(myArray);
```

Try it.